# attempting to create masonry grid with material design lite cards

Tags: javascript, css, masonry, material-design-lite

so i'm making an app that has various material design lite cards with images, such that the cards are in a masonry grid. i'm using the `masonry` module (https://masonry.desandro.com/) to attempt to create a grid in conjunction with `mdl-grid`, but extra whitespace is being added to the end of each card, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRMxT.png)

how do i make it such that the masonry grid is, well, an actual masonry grid? i want to be able to remove this bottom space and place the card under the last one without accounting for the height in other cards in that row.

my full project is available at https://github.com/ix/bunnydb, but the relevant portions are here, in ejs and css:

**(portions of) index.ejs (loaded by express)**

```
<script src="masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
  let elem = document.querySelector('.masonry-grid');
  let msnry = new Masonry(elem, {
    itemSelector: '.masonry-grid-item'
  });
</script>
```

---

```
<div class="mdl-grid masonry-grid">
  <% files.forEach((bun) => { %>
    <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col-desktop masonry-grid-item mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <figure class="mdl-card__media">
        <img src=<%= bun.path.replace("public/", "") %> alt="" />
      </figure>
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h3 class="mdl-card__title-text"><%= bun.originalname %></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--accent mdl-js-button-mdl-js-ripple-effect" href=<%= bun.path.replace("public/", "") %>>
          View
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% }); %>
</div>
```

**index.css**

```
.masonry-grid {
    max-width: auto;
}

.masonry-grid:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.masonry-grid-item {
    /* width: 160px;
    height: 120px; */
    float: left;
}

.mdl-card {
    height: auto;
}

.mdl-card__media {
    margin: 0;
}

.mdl-card__media > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: It looks to me the the `mdl-grid` may be using `display: flex`. Could you try set it to `block`?

Comment: `.mdl-grid { display: block; }` didn't do anything